# maven local cache error

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, dependencies

I am trying to run some `spark` app. The issue is that `maven` seems to found some packages in its local cache repo, but when it tries to load them, it does not find them, indeed some of the package seems to exist but are incomplete in the sense that they don't contain any jar.

Here's the log :

```
com.databricks#spark-avro_2.10 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.databricks#spark-avro_2.10;1.0.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6 in local-m2-cache
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13 in local-m2-cache
    found org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13 in local-m2-cache
    found com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.3 in local-m2-cache
    found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5 in local-m2-cache
    found org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 in local-m2-cache
    found org.tukaani#xz;1.0 in local-m2-cache
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4 in local-m2-cache
:: resolution report :: resolve 484ms :: artifacts dl 22ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.databricks#spark-avro_2.10;1.0.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.3 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.6 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.4.1 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.tukaani#xz;1.0 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5 from local-m2-cache in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   9   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   9   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [NOT FOUND  ] org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5!snappy-java.jar(bundle) (1ms)

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/Users/someuser/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.5/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar

        [NOT FOUND  ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4!slf4j-api.jar (1ms)

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/Users/someuser/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5!snappy-java.jar(bundle)

        :: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4!slf4j-api.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [download failed: org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.0.5!snappy-java.jar(bundle), download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4!slf4j-api.jar]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:995)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I tried to delete `.m2/repository` folder and then run maven again but it did not change anything.

EDIT : here's  my `pom` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spark-ontology</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What remote repos are configured, do the packages it's looking for come from remote sources or local build servers? org.xerial.snappy comes from the xnappy maven repo which needs to be set up in your config, or explicitly named as a repo in the POM. When maven can't find a remote object, it sometimes creates a folder in the .m2. Delete the folder, configure the repos as required and do a 'clean package'

Comment: @Alex I think they come from local source

Comment: Can you post the content of the POM? The xnappy artifact should be in the main maven repo, but it looks like resolution is failing. Deleting the whole .m2 folder is never a good idea, but removing the org.xerial.snappy folder and running 'mvn clean package' should force it to try to resolve the dependency again.

Comment: @Alex sure that's what I did without success. I updated my post with the `pom` file

Comment: @Alex in fact I have some jar file but for the `xerial 1.1.7` but here's dependency needs `1.0.5` . Btw, I have in my local m2 repo, `xerial 1.0.5` directory but withou any jar file inside. Weird isnt' it ?

Comment: Not really, it's a standard practice of Maven. The folder is created in preparation for a jar to be stored. The build is failing because a required jar is missing, but maven hasn't been told what dependency is required. It's not able to resolve it by itself unless it's found in a parent POM

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following dependency -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
    <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven picks up all required dependencies when it prepares the build. If a dependency isn't found, it will throw an error, but unless it is told specifically what dependencies are needed, it can't resolve them.

In this case, it looks like one of the named dependencies requires xerial 1.0.5, so won't compile unless it is provided as an explicitly named dependency.

You will need to run an 'mvn clean package' to force the dependencies to be re-resolved.
You might also need to remove the 1.0.5 directory from within the xerial folder in your .m2 repo before running the 'clean package'. 
Sometimes, maven will see the directory (regardless of whether a jar is in it), and not try to resolve the dependency from the central repo.

It's been some times since I used maven, but I do recall this happening on a few occasions when the network connection had failed while maven was trying to pick up a jar from the repo, leaving the .m2 in an inconsistent state.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this solved the problem.